# Restore webapps progress without JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, database, web-applications

So I have this web app http://goo.gl/qxqhfm and I would like to save the progress (all client side) and restore it next time user opens it, but restore should run without JavaScript, that is users without JavaScript support should be able to load their content.

The app is a bit buggy, e.g. you cant write on orange note before you move it and you cant move the purple one before you enter image url, I'm working on it.

Edit:App is tested only on Chrome

Edit:Is it even posible, to do it wihout JS, and if is, then what language do I use and how is it usualy done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While that is possible, it will be very difficult.

Using the server-side language of your choice, and honestly, any of them could do it, you would simply load the data that was saved and embed it on the page.

If you want to render it, as if the JavaScript ran, you might want to look at `node.js` which is a server-side JavaScript engine and see if you can generate the needed HTML.  `PHP` also has some kind of HTML tools to generate markup, but I know very little about it.

All in all, I really doubt it is worth the effort.  Who is running without JavaScript in today's world?

Comment: That is not the point, I have a task and I need to acomplish that.

Comment: I understand which is why I gave you some directions to look in.

Comment: Yes but, the directions you gave me is Server-Side or JavaScript based

Comment: @user3087101 that is youe only option left. You asked for a non js answer which leaves server side  no other choice

Comment: I hoped that that is not the truth :(